# Javascript is Disabling CSS Hover ...?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following menu: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/alxkI

The "Content" item has a submenu which is shown using the CSS (Code Line 79):

```
&:hover {
  & > ul {
    display: block;
  } // ul
} // hover
```

When I resize it to mobile I use javascript to open / close the submenu on click.

When I resize again to desktop the submenu stops to work ...

It is like the Javascript is disabling the CSS. Is this possible?

What am I missing?

Comment: well i dont exactly understand your question but a mobile may not have a hover.

Comment: what browser are you using in mobile mode??

Comment: I know mobile cannot have hover ... So for mobile version I am using javascript ... I am using only the browser for now in a desktop.

Comment: Try the following: access the page in a desktop ... You will see that the submenu in "Content" shows. Now resize the browser window to make it smaller until the mobile menu appears. Click on content. It shows the submenu ... Now resize back to see the original menu. Try the Content menu. The submenu now does not show ...

Comment: It seems to work for me on latest chrome/osx.  I don't see the submenu in the mobile width though after clicking on Content...

Comment: That is strange and I just checked and it is true ... However in Firefox it works fine ... Anything wrong with my javascript? It seems fine ...